# ActiveRecord DateTime field not matching object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, time

i've got a Course model, which has a datetime attribute. If I look at it from the database i get one time, and if i look at it from the object i get a different date & time.

```
>> Course.last.attribute_for_inspect :datetime
=> "\"2012-01-04 01:00:00\""
>> Course.last.datetime
=> Tue, 03 Jan 2012 19:00:00 CST -06:00
```

Does anyone know why this value is different, and what I can do to fix it? The time from Course.last.datetime is correct, but my queries on the course table aren't working correctly due to the mix-up.

Comment: Your DB stores stuff in UTC without the offset. However, Rails should automatically convert this for you when you query. Can you post the code you're using for one of the broken queries?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1

Comment: what's the value of `config.time_zone` in `application.rb`, provided it's not commented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attribute_for_inspect):

> **attribute_for_inspect**(attr_name)
>   Returns an `#inspect`-like string for the value of the attribute `attr_name`.
>   [...]
>   Date and Time attributes are returned in the `:db` format.

So, when `attribute_for_inspect` is used for a datetime, it will return the string that the database uses for that value. Rails stores times in the database in UTC and any sensible database will use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) for formatting timestamps on the way in and out.

`2012-01-04 01:00:00` is the UTC timestamp in ISO 8601 format. When Rails returns a datetime, it converts it to an [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) instance and includes a timezone adjustment based on the timezone that you have configured in your `application.rb`. You're using the CST timezone and that's six hours behind UTC; subtracting six hours from 01:00 gives you 19:00 and you lose a day from crossing midnight. The human friendly format, `Tue, 03 Jan 2012 19:00:00 CST -06:00`, is just how ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone represents itself when `inspect`ed and the console uses `x.inspect` to display `x`.

As far as fixing your queries goes, just use `t.utc` before sending in a time `t` and you should be good.

Comment: My main issue turned out to be ActiveRecord not correctly handling the date time conversion when using the `DATE()` function, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Configuring your Rails App Timezone in application.rb

set config.active_record.default_timezone to :local as it is set to :utc by default in the application.rb

paste this code in your application.rb

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local #or :utc
config.time_zone = "Singapore" #your timezone
```